# Wireframe mod with Vertex ONLY instances

Tags: vertices

[image]
Hi all. Thx in advance. Any easy workflow for a mesh, which may or may not be complete with faces, edges, and the subsequent vertices - to simply have instances at its main vertices?

A cube, for example, has 8 corners. I intend to place instances at those 8 corners, but instead I get the literal placement(after modifier).

The image shows the ideal outcome on the right. I have 2 meshes there, overlapping and not an ideal workflow, yet.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you ever try geometry nodes?

assuming you want this:

[image]